# Are we allowed to carry airport style checked luggage when using Indian trains?

Tags: trains, luggage, india

I have a luggage bag looking like this:

> [image: suitcase on a selling site]

Would it be allowed to take this with me when I board an Indian train?

Comment: What is the size? Cases in this style come from handbag size to big enough to lay down in, or so it seems. There might well be a size limit.

Comment: Something Like This @Willeke https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsonite-Boost-Spinner-Suitcase-112-5/dp/B01LXFCAZR/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?keywords=flylite+luggage&qid=1700083426&sr=8-5

Comment: Link does not work where I live, can you edit the size into your question please.

Comment: Your new photo still does not mention size. Please give us the size of the case you expect to use, as the style is not the problem but size can be.

Comment: People literally carry the whole village with them. This will be allowed in normal trains. You may have to check for any specs in Vande Bharat trains and Metro trains

Comment: The bag in the link is 48 x 31 x 78 cm, expandable to 48 x 34 x 78 cm. This exceeds the limits as quoted in Franck Dernoncourt's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are we allowed to carry airport style checked luggage when using Indian trains?

Yes. Sources and details (such as weight limits and maximum dimensions):

- https://www.indianrail.gov.in/enquiry/StaticPages/StaticEnquiry.jsp?locale=en&StaticPage=luggage_Rule.html ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEZCs.jpg))
- [https://pib.gov.in/Pressreleaseshare.aspx?PRID=1541065#:~:text=Passengers%20travelling%20over%20all%20Indian,Sleeper%20Class%20and%2035%20Kgs](https://pib.gov.in/Pressreleaseshare.aspx?PRID=1541065#:%7E:text=Passengers%20travelling%20over%20all%20Indian,Sleeper%20Class%20and%2035%20Kgs). ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoKrA.png))

---

Excerpts from the above links:

> Trunks, suitcase and boxes having outside measurement of **100 cms. x 60 cms x 25 cms (length x breadth x height)** will be allowed to be carried in the passenger compartments as personal luggage. If the trunks, suitcase, and boxes, which in outside measurement exceed any one of the dimension, such articles are required to be booked and carried in the brake van and not in the passengers' compartment . Maximum size of the trunks/suitcase than can be carried in the AC-3 tire and AC chair Car compartment is 55 cmsx45 cms x 22.5 cms.
>
> Each passenger is allowed a free allowance up to which he can carry luggage with him in the compartment, free of cost. The free allowance varies for different classes of travel. Children aged 5 and below 12 years are allowed half of the free allowance subject to the maximum of 50 Kgs. You are also permitted a marginal allowance. There is a maximum ceiling on the luggage which can be carried inside the compartment for each class. These are indicated in the table below :
>
> The following maximum limit free allowance, marginal allowance are admissible for carriage of luggage in the compartment :

| Class | Free allowance | Marginal allowance | Maximum quantity permitted ( including free allowance) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC First Class | 70 Kgs | 15 Kgs | 150 Kgs |
| AC 2-Tier sleeper/First class | 50 Kgs | 10 Kgs | 100 Kgs |
| AC 3-tier sleeper/AC chair car | 40 Kgs | 10 Kgs | 40 Kgs |
| Sleeper class | 40 Kgs | 10 Kgs | 80 Kgs |
| Second class | 35 Kgs | 10 Kgs | 70 Kgs |

Comment: Not that anyone on most Indian trains would much care for such rules. Unless you cross someone like the conductor badly, anyways.

Comment: The bag in the OP's link is 48 x 31 x 78 cm, expandable to 48 x 34 x 78 cm. This is too thick, right? So in theory it would have to be carried in the brake van.