# Can we carry luggage on all trains covered by Deutschland ticket?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn, deutschlandticket

To save money I will be travelling between German states using Deutschland ticket trains rather than ICE ones. So, I would like to ask, do all of them have some baggage allowance?

I want to carry luggage similar to as what was described [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184601/are-we-allowed-to-carry-airport-style-checked-luggage-when-using-indian-trains)

Comment: Even if you take more luggage than the answer below suggests, no one is likely to bother you about it.  The Deutschland ticket is only good for local trains, which generally have open seating (no compartments) and no reserved seats.  You get on the train and find a place.  They also carry bicycles.  Outside of rush hour, there will be plenty of space for your luggage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule is, other than your hand luggage, **one** major piece of luggage (or other type of object) that you can carry yourself.

The luggage racks are designed to take pieces that are

- 700 x 500 x 300 mm (height x width x depth)

in size.

There is no mention of different rules for different train or ticket types. Local transportation have similar rules.

I recently saw 5 people carrying one of these:
[image]

So if there is room (and doesn't prevent others from boarding), many things are possible.

---

> [Informationen zur Mitnahme von Gepäck im Zug der Deutschen Bahn](https://www.bahn.de/service/zug/gepaeck)
>
> **Wie viel Gepäck darf ich im Zug mitnehmen?**
> Neben Ihrem Handgepäck dürfen Sie **ein weiteres größeres Gepäckstück** oder einen weiteren Gegenstand kostenlos mitführen, sofern diese sogenannte Traglast **von einer Person allein getragen werden kann**. Aufgrund seiner Größe muss es ggf. außerhalb Ihres Sitzplatzbereichs untergebracht werden, z.B. im nächsten Gepäckregal. Für die Beaufsichtigung des Gepäcks ist jeder Reisende selbst verantwortlich.
> ...
> **Wie groß dürfen meine Gepäckstücke sein?**
> Folgende Standardabmessungen wurden bei der Dimensionierung der Gepäckregale unterstellt und passen fast immer: 700 x 500 x 300 mm (Höhe x Breite x Tiefe).
>
> > **Information about taking luggage on Deutsche Bahn trains**
> >
> > **How much luggage can I take on the train?**
> > In addition to your hand luggage, you can take **another larger piece of luggage** or another item with you free of charge, provided that this so-called **load can be carried by one person alone**. Due to its size, it may have to be stored outside your seat area, e.g. in the next luggage rack. Each traveler is responsible for supervising their own luggage.
> > ...
> > **How big can my luggage be?**
> > The following standard dimensions were assumed when dimensioning the luggage racks and almost always fit: 700 x 500 x 300 mm (height x width x depth).

Comment: More detail in English is available at https://int.bahn.de/en/trains/luggage